# WCF necessary for web app?

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, wcf, web-applications

I'm working on a web app that will connect to a database to store and retrieve and manipulate data, and I was wondeiring if WCF is necessary. I've already deseigned and setup the database and i'm getting ready to start coding the app.

I read up about WCF but what i'm confused about is why i would need to use this layer when i can do the database coding inside the app itself by passing variable values directly into the database with stored procedures.. What am I missing?

BTW, I did research here and didn't see a question similar to this. I went to down two pages and typed "WCF  necessary web app". No relevant hits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF in this context is necessary if, for some reason, you need to have an abstraction layer between the database and the web app **and** you need to have this on another machine (or out-of-process). If that is not the case (likely) there is no need.

You might have noticed guidance to have an abstraction between the database and the web app. There are many pros and cons. Biggest con is effort. If you are not able to articulate clear benefits then you do not need to do this.

You do not "need" to do anything. Do what's right under your specific circumstances and requirements.

Comment: "you need to have an abstraction layer between the database and the web app and you need to have this on another machine (or out-of-process). If that is not the case (likely) there is no need." 

Are you saying If i am putting the database on a different computer then its necessary?

Comment: I have said nothing like that. Not sure what you mean. Notice the word "if".